# Tsql. Результат вывода рекурсии объединить в одну строку таблицы, добавив новые столбцы

Tags: sql, sql-server

дали задание на вывод иерархии объекта из таблицы.На этом сайте https://www.e-du.ru/2016/07/ms-sql-recursive-query-tree.html нашла примерное решение как вывести все дочерние элементы:

```
WITH Recursive (intID, intParentID, strDepartmentName)
AS
(
SELECT intID, intParentID, strDepartmentName
FROM tblDepartment e
WHERE e.intID = 9 
UNION ALL
SELECT e.intID, e.intParentID, e.strDepartmentName
FROM tblDepartment e
    JOIN Recursive r ON e.intParentID = r.intID
)
SELECT intID, intParentID, strDepartmentName
FROM Recursive r
```

Результат получается следующий:
[image]

Как можно объединить строки, чтобы вышла подобная таблица(как пример):

Name1                           |  Name2

Факультет культуры и искусства  |  Кафедра хореографии

Факультет культуры и искусства| Кафедра философии и тд

Comment: Так это ж тупо замена кода на наименование. JOIN ещё одной копии таблицы в основном запросе, или тащить это наименование по всей рекурсивной части в дополнение к коду.

Answer (score 0):

Если не хотите вносить изменения в код рекурсивного CTE, то попробуйте самосоединение:

```
SELECT parent.strDepartmentName, 
child.strDepartmentName
FROM Recursive child 
join Recursive parent 
ON parent.intID=child.intParentID
```